# In python, how do i extract a sublist from a list of strings by matching a string pattern in the original list

Tags: python, regex, list, pattern-matching, sublist

How do i return a sublist of a list of strings by using a match pattern. For example I have

```
myDict=['a', 'b', 'c', 'on_c_clicked', 'on_s_clicked', 's', 't', 'u', 'x', 'y']
```

and I want to return:

```
myOnDict=['on_c_clicked', 'on_s_clicked']
```

I think list comprehensions will work but I'm puzzled about the exact syntax for this.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
import re
myOnDict = [x for x in myDict if re.match(r'on_\w_clicked',x)]
```

should do it...

---

Of course, for this simple example, you don't even need regex:

```
myOnDict = [x for x in myDict if x.startswith('on')]
```

or:

```
myOnDict = [x for x in myDict if x.endswith('clicked')]
```

or even:

```
myOnDict = [x for x in myDict if len(x) > 1]
```

Finally, as a bit of unsolicited advice, you'll probably want to reconsider your variable names.  PEP8 naming conventions aside, these are `list` objects, not `dict` objects.

Comment: Thanks! This works perfectly. Still getting my head around list comprehensions.

Answer (score 0):

Just a guess, but...

```
for entry in myDict:
    if re.search("^on", entry):
        myOnDict.append(entry)
```

Comment: @mgilson's is much more "pythonic" :)

Comment: also, `re.search('^on,...)` is the same thing as `re.match('on',...)` I believe.